# sizeof() in C/C++ for arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof

So C/C++ arrays don't know about their length, right? But then how can the function `sizeof(array)` work and give us the proper size in bytes when it shouldn't be able to know the number of elements in the array?

Comment: ... An example would be useful

Comment: It only knows it when you specify a size at declaration: `int pArray[10]` for example. In all other cases, an array is just a pointer to the first element.

Comment: In scope they were created in, they do. It's when you pass them to functions they decay to pointers to their first element and the information about the size is lost.

Comment: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So C/C++ arrays don't know about their length, right.

Your assumption is wrong. With the exception of variable length arrays introduced in C99, arrays in both C and C++ have a size that is known in compile time. The compiler knows their size.

Your confusion is probably because there are times when array names decay into a pointer to its first element (like when passed as function argument), it's true that the size information is lost here.

But when `sizeof` is used on an array, the array is not converted to a pointer. This is your other confusion: `sizeof` is **not** a function, it's an operator.

Comment: The difference between operators and functions is the syntax sugar. Operators are technically functions.

Comment: @user2341104 What? No, not in C/C++. In particular, with the exception of variable length arrays, `sizeof` is a compile time operator, its operand is not even evaluated.

Comment: Of course it is not evaluated, after all it is known at compile time, there is no point to process known values during the runtime when it can be done during compile time. Not only are operators the same as functions, but in C++ you can create your own operator functions, with the same syntax as a function, the only difference is you specify it is an operator. Normal functions with static parameters are evaluated and pre-calculated during compile time just like the sizeof operator. You can even make operators virtual just like functions.

Comment: @user2341104: your comment is riddled with misunderstandings of the small subtleties of the language. e.g.: operators aren't exactly functions. if you think so, try to overload `&&`.. trust Yu, he's telling you the truth.

Comment: @user2341104 you should know that the assembly code generated for an operator evaluation and a function call are essentially different. Function call involves incrementing the stack pointer, saving return address, making space on the stack for arguments passed to the function by the caller. Of course, I am assuming the function is not inlined. Applying an operator on a operand doesn't involve these.

Comment: @user2341104: Indeed, in C++ overloaded operators are functions. But the built-in operators aren't; and you can't overload the `sizeof` operator in any case. `sizeof` isn't a function, and doesn't behave like one.

Comment: Just because built in primitive operators are "locked" doesn't mean they are something fundamentally different. Operators take in parameters and return values, just like functions do. And despite what some people say, I've substituted regular operators with functions and after compilation the assembly is virtually identical. There are corner case functions just like there are corner case operators, there is really no point in confusing people that operators are something fundamentally different when in reality they are not. The only difference is how some of them take parameters.

Comment: @user2341104: But `sizeof` *is* fundamentally different to a function; the only similarity is that both a function call and a `sizeof` expression are expressions. Its operand can be either an expression or a type specifier; and in the former case it doesn't evaluate the operand. Calling it a function when it behaves fundamentally differently is much more confusing than calling it what it is.

Comment: I think one can describe it somewhat like this: An operator is a syntactic element which gets replaced by something at compiletime. If there is no overloaded operator, the compiler might replace it wich some basic asm-instructions. If it is overladed, it might get replaced with a function call (if not inlined). There are operators which cannot be overloaded like `sizeof` and get replaced with constant values determined by the compiler or simply serve as information to the compiler (`decltype` comes to mind). So an operator is much more than a function.

Comment: All overloaded operators can also be called like a function (`operator==(obj1, obj2)`), but this is not true for built-in oerators.

Comment: C/C++ compilers are about performance, and as such they do everything that can be done during compile time to offload the runtime. Claiming an operator is not a function because its parameter doesn't get evaluated during runtime is RIDICULOUS.

As of `sizeof` - it even takes its parameter in `()` and uses the "function call" operator itself, unlike most of the built in operators. Just because it is built in and its implementation is hidden and locked from modifications doesn't mean it is something different.

Comment: @user2341104 That's where you're wrong: `sizeof` doesn't have to be called using `()`. In fact many prefer to write it as `sizeof int`.

Comment: @Excelcius - I am not wrong, since I never claimed it HAS TO BE CALLED using the `()` operator of the `sizeof` operator. In fact, most users seem to prefer the `()` version, since it is a very rare thing to see `sizeof` in its "operator form". Please do not insinuate stuff you made up just because for some reason people here feel obligated to put me in a wrong context. Functions and operators ARE conceptually the same thing, and just like you can have special operators, you just as easy can have special functions, but that won't make them "non-functions".

Comment: @Excelcius when the operand of `sizeof` is a type, you must enclose it within parentheses.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - how does `sizeof` (and I quote) "behave fundamentally different" than a function? Does it not take a parameter and does it not return a value? I sincerely hope by "behave fundamentally different" you don't mean the simple fact that the compiler just puts the parameter where it needs to be without `()` or the other simple fact it "does not evaluate" which BTW is true only for primitives where it uses a static const value, as the COMPILER DOES EVALUATE user types in order to calculate their size.

Comment: @user2341104 Ok I'm sorry I misread your comment. You really didn't say that you have to call it this way. I thought you were mentioning this to prove that `sizeof` is essentially a function and I believe the fact that it can be written this way is not enough to justify it. I use it with `()` all the time but I do not think of it as a function. That's why I got the example wrong as well. Sorry. But as you said: There are corner cases for operators and while many behave like functions, some don't. So they are not really the same, even if they have many things in common.

Comment: @user2341104 As an example, you can use `sizeof(int)`, can you use a function that takes a parameter that is just `int`?

Comment: If you think of it as a function in a mathematical sense (input something and get something else in return), then yes, operators are functions. But the term function in C++ has a second meaning: usually it implies certain stack mechanisms and some operators are totally unrelated to this concept (can you get a function pointer to point to the `sizeof` function?). But I'm sure there are already lengthy discussions about this on SO and I think we should stop this here in the comments.

Comment: @YuHao - it would make no sense - without an identifier, you cannot refer to that parameter in the body of the function. This is able to work with `sizeof` because its implementation is "internal" and is something like "return the size of the first parameter", but it is a language limitation that you cannot refer to an object without an identifier. In my own programming language (similar to C++) this is possible, because even if you don't declare an explicit identifier, a unique one is created for every object without one. This way I can click on the parameter and refer to it without identif..

Comment: @YuHao - but even in C++, it is perfectly possible to do something like `template <typename T> uint foo(T) { return sizeof(T); }` and while you won't be able to call `foo(int)` you can call `foo(literal)` or `foo(int())`. It is just that C/C++ are very old and dare I say clumsily implemented languages, so there are a lot of limitations, but those do not make operators fundamentally different than functions.

Comment: @user2341104: "how does sizeof (and I quote) "behave fundamentally different" than a function?" To repeat myself: its operand can be either an expression or a type specifier; and in the former case it doesn't evaluate the operand. The operands of functions (including overloaded operators) must be expressions, and are always evaluated. Hence, a `sizeof` expression is fundamentally different from a function call, and trying to call it a function only serves to confuse the definitions of both functions and `sizeof` expressions.

Comment: @user2341104: "the COMPILER DOES EVALUATE user types in order to calculate their size" - no it doesn't, however loudly you shout. In C++ it's never evaluated, since the size of all types is known at compile time. In C, it's only evaluated if it's a variable-length array, since those are freaky things whose size is only known at runtime.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - so evaluation during compilation time is not evaluation? Maybe the compiler has some magical abilities to know user types sizes without evaluating the user types? You activate my hilarity unit :D  I think you have a very limited conceptual mind. Claiming that minor implementation specifics make up for a fundamental difference between operators and functions...

Comment: @user2341104 Try `int i = 42; std::cout << sizeof(i++); std::cout << i;`, and see if the value of `i` changes.

Comment: You all seem to have the same problem with identifying widely used terms with very narrow context situations. Evaluation does not boil down to runtime statement evaluation, there are tons of other things that can be evaluated in tons of different situations. Yes, `sizeof` is implemented a little differently than a normal function, but you could do this to any function in any compiler, and it will still be a function, regardless if it is special/corner case. Doesn't the compiler evaluate user types to calculate their sizes? Do you not realize it is the same thing, just during compile time?

Comment: @user2341104 This is my last comment on this issue, because it seems you won't change your mind no matter what other people told you it's wrong. For this case, it's not up to you or any of us what the definition of **function** is, it's up to the C++ standard. The C++ standard says `sizeof` is not a function, that's it, end of story.

Comment: @YuHao - fair enough. If the standard says `sizeof` is a duck, then it must be duck! :)

Comment: @user2341104: "so evaluation during compilation time is not evaluation?" Yes (as long as the evaluation has no side effects, so that it can be done at compile time). But both languages clearly specify that the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated. It takes the static type of the operand, without evaluating it, and gives the size of that as its value. Unless you're making up your own definition of "evaluate"  (as you are with "function"), rather than using the term as defined by the languages we're discussing, in which case this argument is even more pointless than it already is.

Comment: @user2341104: "Doesn't the compiler evaluate user types to calculate their sizes?" No. "Evaluate" means "find the *value* of an expression"; the compiler only finds the *type* of the expression, and specifically doesn't evaluate it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - user types are evaluated once - on the spot of their definition. Sizeof is likely implemented as something similar to ` return T.size` with size being evaluated in advance. The actual process of size calculation is itself a series of statements, all of which get EVALUATED during compile time in order for the size calculation to be made. I hope you do realize that even at compile time, the compiler itself is a compiled application and the "compile time" is actually the compiler's executable runtime? Sizeof is still evaluated, just not by the app runtime but the compiler runtime.

Comment: @user2341104: "user types are evaluated once" - no they're not. Expressions are evaluated to find their value; types are not evaluated, because they're not values. Even if you do misapply the word to mean "finding the type", you seem to have lost track of what we were discussing: the value of the expression used as the operand of `sizeof` is **not** evaluated, which makes a `sizeof` expression fundamentally different to a function call, since that always evaluates its arguments. For example, `sizeof *null_pointer` is valid, while `f(*null_pointer)` is not.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - I mean the very act of adding the sizes of a type's members and calculating padding involves the evaluation of expressions, don't you THINK? I am sorry, but `sizeof` is still a function, even if it is (usually) evaluated by the compiler's runtime (compile time). And that's what the difference boils down to. And what you've all been telling me is that if a function is evaluated by a runtime other than the application runtime, then it is not a funciton and not evaluation. I think you need to re-evaluate your conceptual mind, and no, I don't mean expression evaluation :)

Comment: @user2341104: I did mean expression evaluation, since that's a fundamental difference between a `sizeof` expression and a function call, which (if you can remember that far back) is what we were discussing before you went off on a tangent trying to redefine "evaluation". `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand the way a function call does; that (to me) is enough justification for regarding them as different entities - as the language specifications do. We're discussing C and C++, which have very definite meanings for the terms "evaluate" and "function", whatever you want them to mean.

Comment: So, if a function is not called but inlined, it is not a function either? Sizeof evaluates its operand(parameter really) the same way every other function does, the difference is not HOW but WHEN it is evaluated. And it is evaluated, because if it wasn't there would be no way for the expression to have any meaning, since you cannot possibly come up with a value result without evaluation.

Comment: What's more, in some cases `sizeof` actually does behave like a function. Which makes things even more confusing, first you say operators are different from functions, but then, sometimes they are the same (user declared operators) so it is not a function... unless the cases where it is a function. I just go the extra level of abstraction and call it all FUNCTIONS, because that's what they ultimately are when you abstract from the implementation details. This wraps up everything nice and clean.

Comment: @user2341104: "So, if a function is not called but inlined, it is not a function either?" Of course it is. The program will still behave *as if* its arguments were evaluated; it will never behave as if the operand of `sizeof` were evaluated. `f(printf("Hello"))` will produce output; `sizeof(printf("Hello"))` won't, because the `printf` expression is never evaluated.

Comment: @user2341104: "you cannot possibly come up with a value result without evaluation." - exactly. `sizeof` **doesn't need** the value of its operand; only the type of the expression. For that reason, the language specifies that it doesn't evaluate that expression; it just finds its type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - and the type magically collapses to an integer value? Without internally using some expression evaluation like `return T.size()` in the compiler runtime? Where does this value come from if not from evaluating an expression?

Comment: @user2341104: "and the type magically collapses to an integer value?" It's not magic; but yes, the compiler knows the size of the type, so can provide the value. "Without internally using some expression evaluation" - you're wilfully ignoring the fact that I'm referring to the evaluation of a specific expression: the operand of `sizeof`, versus the argument of a function call. One is never evaluated; one is always evaluated; that is a "fundamental difference" between a `sizeof` expression and a function call, which (long, long ago) is what you challenged me to provide.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - now seriously, you said "sizeof doesn't need the value of its operand; only the type of the expression" - and in this you are conflicting yourself. The compiler extracts the size value from the type value, if there is no value associated with the type, then there would be no reference from where to get the size value, e.g. for which type it is. Of course that the operand type is evaluated, only this way the compiler can figure out that it needs the size value for that particular type. How are you not getting it?

Comment: @user2341104: "first you say operators are different from functions, but then, sometimes they are the same" - we're discussing `sizeof`, not operators in general. `sizeof` is not a function (per the language's definition of "function"), doesn't behave like a function (since it doesn't evaluate its operand), and can't be overloaded with a function.

Comment: For the last time, `sizeof` does evaluate its parameter. It happens during compile time, so runtime evaluations are not included. But that doesn't mean it is not evaluated. Are you really telling me that compile time evaluation is not evaluation? That's like saying only home made muffins are baked, because you baked them yourself, and those made in a muffin factory are not, simply because it already happened and you didn't see it. So factory muffins must come into existence already baked and there is no baking involved...

Comment: @user2341104: "For the last time, sizeof does evaluate its parameter" - for the last time, no it does not. It finds the static type of the expression, but **not** its value - not at compile time, not at run time, not ever. Any side-effects of evaluation will not happen. The `sizeof` expression is still valid if the operand can't be evaluated - if it calls an undefined function, or dereferences an invalid pointer, or causes infinite recursion, for example. This is fundamentally different to a function call, which **does** evaluate its argument's value.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and open up a compiler implementation. And I am pretty sure you will get the Nobel price (at least) if you manage to come up with a way to fetch an object's property without evaluating which object it is.

Comment: I mean why even pass a parameter/operand to sizeof, since from what you say, one can get the clear idea what you pass is not evaluated in any way whatsoever. Maybe now you are beginning to understand what I mean?

Comment: @user2341104: It's not an "object's property"; it's a property of a *type*, which exists whether or not there are any objects of that type. The compiler works out the type of the expression - in a statically-typed language, that does **not** require evaluation.

Comment: @user2341104: "I mean why even pass a parameter/operand to sizeof, since from what you say, one can get the clear idea what you pass is not evaluated in any way whatsoever" - as I've said many times the **type** (not the **value**) of the operand is used to determine the value of the `sizeof` expression. The **type** is a static property of the expression, and can be determined without evaluating the **value**. The **value** of the operand is not evaluated. Both languages are very clear on this point.

Comment: So now a type is a type not an object with properties such as type, alignment, size and so on? What is a type if not a value reference to a place you can get information on that type? So you magically come up with a size of every type, without evaluating which type it is? Because so far that's what you've been saying. There is no process involved in sizeof similar to "ok return the size for THAT type" - something I'd say passes perfectly for "evaluation". And on a further note, how DOES a compiler distinguish between types, when all computers can understand is VALUES?

Comment: How do computers understand values without evaluating them?

Comment: @user2341104: I never said it didn't determine the type - that's a straw man you keep repeating, which is clearly not true. As I keep saying: The **value** of the operand is **not** evaluated. The **value** of a function call's argument **is** evaluated. That is a fundamental difference between functions and `sizeof` expressions, and a reason to regard them as separate entities.

Comment: So, this happens but it has nothing to do with values and evaluation of such? Too proud to admit your wrongness? Either admit that or explain to me how do computers distinguish values without evaluation them. How can the sizeof "operator" return the size for a given type without evaluating which type it is?

Comment: @user2341104: "How do computers understand values without evaluating them?" They don't. But (as I keep saying), a `sizeof` expression doesn't need the value **of its operand**, so does not evaluate **its operand**. To be clear: I'm **not** saying that it doesn't evaluate anything (in some sense of the word "evaluate") - that's just your straw man.

Comment: @user2341104: "How can the sizeof "operator" return the size for a given type without evaluating which type it is?" It couldn't, which is why I never said it could. It doesn't evaluate **the value** of its operand.

Comment: So, `sizeof` "evaluates" values without "evaluating them". This keeps on getting better and better. Come on man, it is not that hard. You pass a type to sizeof, the compiler evaluates the sizeof statement, checks the value of the type and returns its associated size. You really can't see the "evaluation" in that process?

Comment: @user2341104: "So, sizeof "evaluates" values without "evaluating them"." No. It determines (or evaluates, if you like) the **type** of the expression, but does not evaluate **the value** of the expression.  Could you please stop insisting that I'm claiming it doesn't "evaluate" anything? I'm just saying that it does not calculate the **value** of the operand, unlike a function call, which does calculate the **value** of its argument(s).

Comment: But hey, I cannot say I don't understand you. If in your mind all that "evaluation" refers to is runtime statement evaluations, then your position will make sense, because you simply cannot evaluate your claims. All you can evaluate is runtime statements :)

Comment: @user2341104: No, compile time versus runtime is irrelevant. Either the value of an expression is calculated or it isn't. The value of the `sizeof` operand is not calculated; the value of a function call argument is calculated before the function is called. So, to repeat my example, `f(printf("Hello"))` has side effects; `sizeof(printf("Hello"))` does not, because `printf("Hello")` is never evaluated. That's a fundamental difference between the two entities, which is what you (originally) challenged me to provide before getting sidetracked with wierd strawman arguments about evaluation.

Comment: LOL, "it does not evaluate, it determines by means of evaluation"...
"I'm just saying that it does not calculate the value of operand, unlike a function call" - where did I say it is calculating values? And what values do you mean? What value is calculated when I call `foo(bar)` ? I am guessing what you mean is that "expressions are not evaluated" in `sizeof` - something I stated a long time ago, since usually sizeof is evaluated during compile time, so logically runtime expressions are not evaluated during compile time. But that doesn't mean the type value is in no way evaluated.

Comment: "it does not evaluate, it determines by means of evaluation" - no. It determines the **type** without evaluating the **value**. Unlike a function call, which **does** evaluate the value.

Comment: "What value is calculated when I call foo(bar) ?" The function's return value (or none, if it doesn't have one).

Comment: " It determines the type without evaluating the value" How do you determine which type it is if you don't evaluate it in some way? Don't you like... have to take a value or something to figure what that value is? That's what keeps on slipping.

Comment: "But that doesn't mean the type value is in no way evaluated." I NEVER SAID THAT. I'm describing a difference between `sizeof` and function calls, to counter your claim that they're the same thing. Function calls evaluate the value of their arguments. `sizeof` doesn't evaluate the value of its operand. That's all I'm claiming. Please stop the weird strawman claims that it doesn't evaluate anything.

Comment: @user2341104: "Don't you like... have to take a value or something to figure what that value is? " Not in a statically-typed language. Every expression has a static type, determined from the types of its sub-expressions, and available to the compiler without evaluating the expression's value. For example, we don't have to call `printf("Hello")` to know that the expression has type `int` - the declaration of `printf` tells the compiler all it needs to know.

Comment: @user2341104: And if my argument isn't convincing enough, the C language specification says, for `sizeof`, "If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, **the operand is not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant." while, for a function call, "In preparing for the call to a function, **the arguments are evaluated**". C++ is similar.

Comment: I perfectly understand the different way in which `sizeof` works compared to regular functions, so far you've wasted time explaining stuff that I already know. But even a corner case function is still a function. Fact is `sizeof` has no way to determine which size it must return without evaluating the type value provided to it. It is that simple. If `sizeof` didn't involve any evaluation, then it wouldn't need a parameter/operand supplied to it. The very and only reason you pass a parameter to it is so that compiler can evaluate what it is and and do its thing. It is common sense...

Comment: @user2341104: Sorry for wasting your time; when you asked "how does sizeof (and I quote) "behave fundamentally different" than a function?", I assumed you wanted an answer - one evaluates its operand/argument, the other doesn't (and can therefore be used in situations where the other can't). You still don't seem to understand the difference between determining an expression's type and evaluating its value, but I don't think further explanations will help there. Goodbye.

Comment: This has gone somewhat off-topic a long time ago, consider continuing this discussion in chat. By now it should be obvious that one of you is talking about the C/C++ standard terms which clearly state what a function is and what evaluation does or does not mean. The other one of you is talking about far more general concepts. The language standard describes compile-time mechanics and runtime mechanics of the compiled program. Clearly the compiler is also a program and will have to do evaluation of some sort but that is not the type of evaluation the languag specification talks about.

Comment: So, something like `template <typename T> uint sizeof(T) { return T.size(); }` is fundamentally different from a normal function how exactly? You pass a parameter, and in the function you return a property of that parameter. Just like in every function. For me "fundamentally different" would mean that the function throws the parameter out of the windows and does a bunch of random stuff instead.  As I already said, you need to polish on your conceptual mind, your concept of "evaluation" is just as limited as your concept of "fundamentally different"...

Comment: @MikeSeymour - my sincere apologies, should have first noted that you have asked exactly zero questions here, so if there is a reason you are here, it is most likely praising rather than disagreement and discussion. That explains your complete refusal to take in anything from what I've said and instead keeping on insisting stuff that I'm already aware of. Both you and I are "corner cases" people,  unfortunately on the two opposite corners. I still keep my common sense and would not jump off a bridge just because the standard says so. It is concepts that move things and come before standards.

Comment: And since the standard is apparently all that matters, I am willing to admit I am wrong if someone would provide me with a quote in which the standard explicitly labels operators as "fundamentally different from functions. Especially considering the fact that all user operators are technically functions, and I can only assume a sane and logical thing would be for built in operators to be the same, even if limited strictly to compile time evaluation. Otherwise I'd assume I am right, since I do not expect Mike to admit to presenting the standard in an unrealistically dramatic way.

Comment: Are you kidding me? It's so nice of @MikeSeymour to be patient and explain things to you, I myself gave up long time ago. This discussion has become not about the question long ago, please don't post comments here any more. If you have a question, ask a new question, and see what other people think about it.

Comment: @user2341104: Sorry if you don't like the word "fundamental"; but the difference can affect both the behaviour of a program (since evaluating an expression can have side effects), and its validity (since not all expressions can be evaluated), which seems quite fundamental to me. And sorry for the confusion over whether or not we were talking about standard C terminology; it's usually better to stick to that terminology when discussing C, in order to avoid this kind of confusion. And sorry to everyone for continuing to feed the troll as the argument became increasingly pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I will quote the relevant portions of C99 standard. §6.5.3.4 ¶2 says

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
>   is an integer constant.

It also says in the same section §6.5.3.4 ¶1

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type.

About the array type, §6.2.5 ¶20 says

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
>   objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.
>   Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number
>   of elements in the array.

It again says in §6.2.5 ¶22

> An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type.

---

So to summarize the above, the size of an array is known to the compiler (determined using `sizeof` operator) when you also specify the size of the array, i.e, when it's a complete type.